# Multi module project analysis with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

`SonarQube Server 5.1.2, Sonar-Runner 2.4`

As provide in [Multi-moduleProject](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeRunner-Multi-moduleProject) i have created a project structure as

```
Accounts
|
->invoice
  |
   ->src

->receipt
  |
   ->src

->sonar.properties
```

File:sonar.properties

```
sonar.projectKey=org.mycompany.acc
sonar.projectName=Account
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=src

sonar.modules=invoice,receipt

invoice.sonar.projectName=Invoice
receipt.sonar.projectName=Receipt
```

When execute with above configuration in sonar-runner i encountered with error "src" folder is missing in "Account" directory, hope this configuration is same as the conf available in that link. As per the understanding if the configuration is fine then the Invoice and Receipt will be listed as **sub project** under Account Project, so what are the changes are required in above configuration to achieve multi module / project under one project.

**ERROR**

`ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: The folder 'src' does not exist for 'org.mycompany.acc' (base
directory = C:\Users\xyz\Accounts\.)
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with t
he -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.`

Comment: Is it an "error" or just an warning?

Comment: So you need to specify the base directory for the modules.

Comment: @BheshGurung , ya even tried that to `sonar.projectBaseDir=C:/Users/xyz/Accounts` but still getting the same error. Its resolve only if i had `src` folder in `C:/Users/xyz/Accounts` path, but it should refer the src from module folders right?

Comment: What is your version of SonarQube and SonarQube Runner?

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam SonarQube Server 5.1.2, Sonar-Runner 2.4

Comment: The base directory should be the one that contains the src directory. You obviously dont have src in Accounts directory.

Comment: @jerith2 it is like if the sonar.modules properties is not taken into account. Can you double check there is no typo or extra character. You can try to run the analysis with -DsonarRunner.dumpToFile=out.txt and inspect the content. This is the properties like SonarQube "see" them.

Comment: Can you post all the output on the console window?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try this:

```
sonar.projectKey=org.mycompany.acc
sonar.projectName=Account
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=src # try to remove this by the way if you don't have suchdirectory under root folder of project

sonar.modules=invoice,receipt

invoice.sonar.projectName=Invoice
invoice.sonar.sources=invoice/src
receipt.sonar.projectName=Receipt
receipt.sonar.sources=receipt/src
```

Comment: works with sonarqube version 6, SonarQube Scanner 2.8

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Sonar 6.2 per https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages

Comment: As per the docs link above, you can achieve a similar thing by putting a nested `sonar.properties` file inside each module directory, and override just the relevant settings.

Comment: sonarqube scanner 3.3 works in our ends

Answer (score -1):

You can try this option, If you want scan multiple projects at same time OR in same build then try this option.

> sonar.sources=invoice,receipt

Answer (score -1):

`sonar.modules` property was deprecated long time ago. Use `sonar.sources` parameter to perform a scan.
In short, you have to specify in `sonar:sonar` goal parameters where the sources and reportPaths are located for the required modules and declare jacoco configuration for each module respectively. As a result, it will look something like this:

1. Jacoco plugin declaration in each module:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
     <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>0.8.7</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
             <goals>
                 <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
         <execution>
             <id>report</id>
             <phase>test</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>report</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```

2. Sonar goal execution:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar /
-Dsonar.projectKey=... /
-Dsonar.host.url=... /
-Dsonar.login=... /
-Dsonar.branch.name=... /
-Dsonar.sources=../module1/src/main,../module2/src/main / 
-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=module1/target/jacoco.exec,module2/target/jacoco.exec
```

Important! It's required to specify `..` before module name in `-Dsonar.sources` parameter because jacoco plugin in each module can only read content by relative path from it's location.