# How to trigger sonarqube analysis for multi-module Scala project?

Tags: scala, sonarqube, multi-module

I need to analyse a multi-module Scala legacy project in Sonarqube v7.6 that has the Scala plugin already installed.

I am not very used to Scala and I overheard someone at the office saying it's not a standard project. Inside [ROOT_DIR] there is a folder `app`, that has only the launcher. Then I have `domain` and `roles` folders which contains modules, in `[ROOT_DIR]/domain/[MODULE]/src` and `[ROOT_DIR]/roles/[MODULE]/src`.

I have tried a few things with no data being passed to Sonarqube. One of the most promising leads is from this question: [Multi module project analysis with SonarQube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227360/multi-module-project-analysis-with-sonarqube).

I don't mind having a `sonar-project.properties` file I can just run `sbt sonarScan` off the [ROOT_DIR] and check the analysis in sonarqube.

So far my `sonar-project.properties` looks like:

```
sonar.projectKey=myProject
sonar.sources=src/main/scala


sonar.login=e0fc3c8acf7028ebaca34bd5ddfb740d5498ee39
sonar.tests=src/test/scala
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.scala.version=2.12
sonar.modules=moduleA, moduleB, moduleC

moduleA.sonar.projectName=moduleA
moduleA.sonar.sources=domain/moduleA/src
moduleB.sonar.projectName=moduleB
moduleB.sources=domain/moduleB/src
moduleC.sonar.projectName=moduleC
moduleC.sonar.sources=domain/moduleC/src
```

While this looks good, I am getting the following error:

`[error] (moduleA / sonarScan) Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.`

The login and password error is a bit weird because Sonarqube is behind OneLogin so I don't have any issues scanning the other projects that use Maven and Java/Kotlin.

How can I get this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue with `sbt sonarScan -Dsonar.java.binaries=target`. With this, the `sonar-project.properties` is (apparently!) not needed.